# Defining a pointer to a list in C++

Tags: c++, list, pointers

I'm new at C++ programming and I'm having troubles trying to define a pointer to a list. This is the code I'm trying to use:

```
list<int>* pl;
```

The error:

```
/home/julian/Proyectos Code::Blocks/pruebas/main.cpp|17|error: expected type-specifier before ‘list’|
```

Is it posible to define a pointer to a list? I need to have a function that returns a pointer to a list.

Thank you very much

Comment: Did you `#include <list>` with `using namespace std;`? It sounds like it doesn't know what `list` refers to.

Comment: Are you sure you need a pointer at all?

Comment: @Julian To expand on the previous point, if you have a modern compiler (supporting C++11), you can return a std::list as if by value with no copying cost due to the fact that std::list and all other std data structures have [move constructors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Rvalue_references_and_move_constructors).  Prior to C++11 you could have passed in the std::list by reference instead of returning a pointer to it.

Answer (score 12):

You have to include the `list` header and qualify the name `list`:

```
#include <list>

std::list<int> *p;
```

Alternatively:

```
using std::list;
list<int> *p;
```

Comment: @Benj It imports way too much stuff indiscriminately opening the door for conflicts - the very problem namespaces set out to solve.

Answer (score 3):

`list` resides in `std` namespace. So try doing -

```
std::list<int>* pl;
```

Comment: I was having a typo in another part of my code. It's working now, with the code I posted before. Do you know if I can delete the original question? Thank you anyway.

Comment: You can. But I amn't sure if you need to have sufficient reputation to delete your own question.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
std::list<int>* pl;
```